# Loader not retained and always created on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, loader, android-loadermanager

I have an `Activity A` that contains a `Fragment B` that contains a `Fragment C`.

Currently, `Fragment B`'s `LoaderManager` manages one `CursorLoader`. The data is given to `Fragment C`.

On orientation change, the loader is lost: `initLoader` always leads to `onCreateLoader` being invoked by the system. However, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>)) says:

> If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. Otherwise the last created loader is re-used.

How do I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an open bug, Google is aware and hopefully plan on fixing it

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183783

Comment: Can I ask a stupid question: does this mean 1) users will have to wait for an OS update or 2) I just wait for a new "compileSdkVersion" against which to compile my code? or 3) something else? I am a bit confused about how my code interacts with the OS version on the phone.

Comment: You can target a lower version of the appcompat library and you should not have this issue until they either fix it or issue a statement about it.